# Failed to run react native android setup

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to run a react native application in android (WIndows10) .But i am getting the error like this

[image]

I have installed android sdk using Android Studio 2.3.1.Contents in my

> AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools

[image]

Please help on this issue?

Comment: try to remove older versions of 23 and only keep latest version of 23 i.e 23.0.3.. may do a trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating Android SDK from your android studio. Once the update is done. Add the `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable inside system variables, point the path to your sdk directory(this is my path for sdk D:\Android\sdk).